# neovim indentation shifts to the beginning of the line when navigating up through blank spaces"

Tags: indentation, neovim, auto-indent

When entering insert mode with 'o,' auto-indentation aligns well with existing code. Creating new lines downwards with 'Enter' maintains the expected indentation. However, moving back up through these blank lines  shifts the cursor to the beginning of the line. Any idea how to fix it?